# NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle - but it's there, sort of

Tags: ios, xib, runtime-error

Seemingly, out of the blue, I am now getting this message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/CC7C18ED-8A1D-4548-86F1-B868B50D2535/YesTheApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'ECLNameAndattributeCell''
```

When I look in Copy Bundle Resources in Build Phases (as suggested by other similar questions) I see the following. All my other nib files are showing that they are in my app but ECLNameAndAttributeCell.xib is the only one that has no text after it.

[image: Notice that ECLNameAndAttributeCell does not say ...inYes ...]

Nor is it listed in the list of files that I could add.

I also looked at its Kind in Finder and it said it was an Interface Builder XIB Document. How do I check the File Type in Xcode? I read to right click on the file in Xcode. Is that control-click? I don't see any option to check the file type with a control-click in the menu that appears.

BTW, the app seems to run fine on the simulator after I removed and reinstalled the app on the simulator. But it consistently crashes on the iPhone, even after removing and rerunning the app on the iPhone.

Can someone explain what is going on and what I should do?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, right click is control click.

You need to show the File Inspector, then select the file in the Project Navigator,  The File Type should be the second line in the inspector.  This will also allow you to see check the file localization and target membership.  If the target membership is not correct, the file may not be getting updated.

Comment: Thanks Steven for pointing out how to understand how to use this feature.

Answer (score 4):

You're spelling it wrong, it's `ECLNameAndAttributeCell`, with a capital A on Attributed.

Comment: Thank you hwaxxer for catching that. It worked like a charm on my iPhone after I fixed it. Not sure how it worked for a while but thanks again.

Comment: The simulator is not case sensitive.